# Управляемое и обычное приложение 1с 8.2

Tags: 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю простую процедуру:

```
Процедура ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы()
    Предупреждение("Внимание!",60);
    Сообщить("Сегодня " + ТекущаяДата()); 
КонецПроцедуры
```

в управляемом приложении все запускается и работает, а в обычном нет (меняем в конфигураторе - свойства - Основной режим запуска:). Вопрос: Почему не работает и где про это можно почитать подробно, какие еще моменты не будут работать в обычном и управляемом. Ну и как тогда надо сделать, чтобы заработало?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обычного приложения свой модуль. Когда меняете в свойствах конфигурации Основной режим запуска на "Обычное приложение" появляется чуть ниже ссылка на модуль обычного приложения (также появляется дополнительный пункт контекстного меню для конфигурации). В этом модуле нужно создать соответствующий обработчик ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы.

Вот [статейка](http://infostart.ru/public/83546/) про различные виды модулей в 1С.

Answer (score 0):

А еще есть очень интересная в этом плане книга от 1С - Архитектура и работа с данными "1С:Предприятие 8.2" из серии "Профессиональная разработка"